# "es gibt es" - what does it mean?

Tags: expression

On the webpage of Tagesschau.de (1) there is this sentence:

"Aber es gibt es natürlich auch eine ganze Reihe von Ansätzen, um sich im Vorfeld besser vorzubereiten."

I am puzzled by the "es gibt es", more exactly by the second "es".

What is the meaning of it? Is this usual, or is this a special construction?

Thank you.

(1) https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/gesellschaft/hydrologe-hochwasserschutz-101.html

Comment: The second “es” is indeed an error, it shouldn’t be there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a 3rd party mistake.